# Scraping Data From HTML With Multiple Elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the `data-ppu` value from this line of HTML code called `trade_data`:

```
<input class="tradeForm" data-id="10397992" data-ppu="3893" data-toggle="tooltip" maximum="16450" name="rcustomamount" title="Enter Your Desired Amount" type="number" value="16450"/>
```

I'm using Python 3 and Beautiful Soup. Here's the code I've tried:

```
for index, trade_data in enumerate(trade_data):
   price = trade_data.find('data-ppu')
   print(price)
```

However this returns nothing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the attributes, you need to do like this:

- Since the `data-ppu` is an attribute of the `<input>` tag, you need to first select it and then extract it's attributes.

##### Selecting the `<input>` tag

> `x = soup.find('input')`

##### Extracting the attribute `data-ppu`

> `x['data-ppu']`

Here is the complete code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """
<input class="tradeForm" data-id="10397992" data-ppu="3893" data-toggle="tooltip" maximum="16450" name="rcustomamount" title="Enter Your Desired Amount" type="number" value="16450"/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')
x = soup.find('input')
print(x['data-ppu'])
```

```
3893
```

Comment: This was extremely helpful- thank you. I had completely neglected the `input` tag, and this solution cleared that up.

Answer (score 0):

What you've asked for is all of the `<data-ppu>` tags, of which there are none.  You need to search the attributes of the tag:

```
for part in trade_data:
    price = part.findAll( lambda tag: tag.name='input' and 'data-ppu' in tag.attrs)
```